# Only valid API states vs React reconcilliation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I model my types for backend API returns to represent only valid (legal) states:

```
interface ApiInit {
  kind: 'init';
}
interface ApiSuccess<T> {
  kind: 'success';
  data: T;
}
interface ApiFail {
  kind: 'fail';
  errors: string[];
}
interface ApiLoading {
  kind: 'loading';
}

type ApiReturn<T> = ApiSuccess<T> | ApiFail | ApiLoading | ApiInit
```

However, in the example below, since only `ApiSuccess` type has `data` attribute on it, whenever API goes into the success state React seems to treat the data it receives as a completely new array, resetting all the possible internal states the nested components might have had:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

interface ApiInit {
  kind: 'init';
}
interface ApiSuccess<T> {
  kind: 'success';
  data: T;
}
interface ApiFail {
  kind: 'fail';
  errors: string[];
}
interface ApiLoading {
  kind: 'loading';
}

type ApiReturn<T> = ApiSuccess<T> | ApiFail | ApiLoading | ApiInit

type IOrg = { name: string };

const api = {
  getOrgs: async () => ({
    data: [{ name: 'org1' }, { name: 'org2' }],
    errors: [],
  }),
};

const useApi = <T,>(apiFunc) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<ApiReturn<T>>({kind: 'init'});

  const request = async () => {
    setState({ kind: 'loading' });
    const { data, errors } = await apiFunc();
    if (errors.length) {
      setState({ kind: 'fail', errors });
    } else {
      setState({ kind: 'success', data });
    }
  };
  return { state, request };
};

const Org = ({org}: {org: IOrg}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('not updated')
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{org.name}</div>
      <div>{state}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setState('updated')}>Update</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const Orgs = ({orgs}: {orgs: IOrg[]}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {orgs.map(org => <Org key={org.name} org={org} />)}
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const orgsApi = useApi<IOrg[]>(api.getOrgs);
  // const [orgs, setOrgs] = useState<IOrg[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    orgsApi.request()
  }, [])

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   orgsApi.state.kind === 'success' && setOrgs(orgsApi.state.data)
  // }, [orgsApi.state])

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={orgsApi.request}>Get orgs</button>
      {orgsApi.state.kind === 'success' && <Orgs orgs={orgsApi.state.data} />}
    </div>
  )
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Interactive demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qcksye?file=index.tsx)

To reproduce the issue, please open the demo, click some `update` buttons and then `get orgs`. You will see that the internal state of each `Org` component resets to `not updated`.

Is there any way to keep the types pattern I have (only valid API states) and still make React reconcile components instead of creating new ones? Preferably without introducing any helper state, only using `state` that `useApi` hook returns.